# TYPO3: get and display all file categories in fluid

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid

**TYPO3 11.5.33**

**Task**
I want to display every category title of a pdf file in a comma separated list in a table column.

I have the content element of `CType` = uploads and inside I have a `sys_file_collection` for a folder with pdf files.
I iterate over the `{files}` array to create a table with columns for example a preview icon, file title, file size and the categories, which were assigned to the file.

```
<f:for each="{files}" as="file" iteration="fileIterator">
<!-- table code -->
</f:for>
```

For example:

```
   Image    |   Title   |  Category  | Filesize
preview pic   PDF Title   cat1, cat2     3 MB
preview pic   PDF Title2  cat3           5 MB
```

Everything is working except the output of the categories.

If I debug the `{file}` array I get the following information:

[image: Debug information]

and inside `metaDataAspect` there are a lot of properties.

There is `categories` but this has only an `integer` value, for the number of categories which are selected for that file.

[image: categories]

In the Slack channel I was told a `dataProcessor` is best suited for this use case and was recommended this https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/DatabaseQueryProcessor.html

After spending some time on it I have no idea how to get this working.

I also found this WIP task https://forge.typo3.org/issues/82010 | https://review.typo3.org/c/Packages/TYPO3.CMS/+/62123 but it's still not finished and I'm also not sure if that would work with files.

Is there really no out-of-the-box solution for this problem?

Had someone a similar problem already and can help with a solution or is there an existing vhs viewhelper for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

The output of the `uploads` CE (content Element) is configured  in your typoscript at `tt_content.uploads`. There you can find the `FilesProcessor` which provides your list of file data for the FLUID.

As you noticed the `category` field is just added as is without resolving the relation.

You can/ must add another processor (a `databaseQueryProcessor`) for resolving these relation:

```
tt_content {
  uploads {
    dataProcessing {
      10 {
        dataProcessing [
          10 = TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\DataProcessing\DatabaseQueryProcessor
          10 {
            if.isTrue.field = categories
            table = sys_category
            pidInList = root,-1
            selectFields = sys_category.*
            join = sys_category_record_mm ON sys_category_record_mm.uid_local = sys_category.uid
            where.data = field:_ORIG_uid // field:uid
            where.intval = 1
            where.wrap = sys_category_record_mm.uid_foreign=|
            orderBy = sys_category_record_mm.sorting_foreign
            languageField = 0 # disable translation handling of sys_category
            as = categoryList
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

---

In the [manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/ContentObjects/Fluidtemplate/DataProcessing/CustomDataProcessors.html) you can find an example for a `customCategoryProcessor` which handles exactly your problem. The needed PHP is given in the ['TYPO3 explained'-manual](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/ApiOverview/ContentElements/CustomDataProcessing.html#content-elements-custom-data-processor)

Comment: Are those 2 approaches, how to handle the problem? Either use the `DatabaseQueryProcessor` which should list the categories or use a `customCategoryProcessor`. I added the `DatabaseQueryProcessor` Typoscript but there is no `categoryList` in fluid available.

Comment: I haven't that typoscript in use as I havn't had this request till now. maybe the query is not complete. I used an example for categories on pages I found and adapted it to your problem. Maybe I missed something. As I have no time and example installation I can't help much further. maybe someone else can help you here or on slack.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I only adapted the `pidInList` to use the page where the categories are stored (pidInList = 500) and fixed the bracket square in line 5. Even if I remove some elements to make it less complex, just to see if there is any output at all in the fluid variable it doesn't work. `categoryList` does not appear, even empty.

Comment: next step to debug would be to inspect the generated query. try to build an failing query to find it in an error message or log (as far as you can not see the database-log instantly). then compare it with your data.

Comment: Here's an update on that topic:
A coworker looked also into the matter and said that it looks like that a FileDataprocessor can't have a nested DatabaseQueryProcessor.
As reference I was given this: public/typo3/sysext/frontend/Classes/DataProcessing/FilesProcessor.php and to compare with other DatabaseQueryProcessors.

Is that possible?

Comment: as said: I have no installation to test this. If you can't prepare the data in the controller you might use a viewhelper to get the desired information. In this case it might be a VH with the `uid` of the file (`sys_file` or 'sys_file_metadata`) to handle it in PHP or even Typoscript (1. getting the `sys_file_metadata` record if not given 2. getting the `sys_category` records)